# Show price on input select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a restaurant website. I created a form with select option and I want it that if someone selects any of the options, a price for that option will appear. I know JavaScript should be used but I am not that good in JavaScript.

```html
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="menu">Food: </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <select name="menu" id="menu" required>
      <option value="jollof" selected>Jollof w/ chicken</option>
      <option value="jollof">Plain Rice w/ chicken</option>
      <option value="jollof">Salad w/ chicken</option>
      <option value="jollof">Jollof w/ Fish</option>
      <option value="jollof">Plain Rice w/ chicken</option>
      <option value="jollof">Fufu w/ chicken</option>
      <option value="jollof">Fufu w/ Goat Meat</option>
      <option value="jollof">Fufu w/ Fish</option>
      <option value="jollof">Chips w/ Chicken</option>
      <option value="jollof">Chips w/ Fish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case it depends on where the price is coming from?

Comment: Great, you have shared your markup. However, how is the pricing data being made available? Without that we will have no idea what to do.

Comment: i was able to figure out and i solved it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the `value` of the `option` tags according to your prices.

```js
var drop = document.getElementById("menu");
var price = document.getElementById("price");
drop.onchange = function() {
price.innerHTML = "$" + drop.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="menu">Food: </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <select name="menu" id="menu" required>
<option value="10" selected>Jollof w/ chicken</option>
<option value="20" >Plain Rice w/ chicken</option>
<option value="30" >Salad w/ chicken</option>
<option value="40" >Jollof w/ Fish</option>
<option value="50" >Plain Rice w/ chicken</option>
<option value="60" >Fufu w/ chicken</option>
<option value="70" >Fufu w/ Goat Meat</option>
<option value="80" >Fufu w/ Fish</option>
<option value="90" >Chips w/ Chicken</option>
<option value="100" >Chips w/ Fish</option>
</select>
  </div>
  <p id="price"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. i guess i should start with javascript asap